# Построение дерева из базы данных

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

В результате выполнения SQL-запроса, получаю следующие данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если `PAR_Id = 0` - это root node. Результатом запроса - порядка 10000 записей.

Какую оптимальную структуру данных выбрать для построение такого дерева? Может кто поспособствует построению этого дерева, буду безмерно благодарен.

**UPD**

Хотелось бы получить, вот такую структуру:
[image: Дерево]

Answer (score 1):

Оптимальный вариант - список смежности, нужно в этом направлении гуглить.
Если вкратце, то нужно что-то типа такого:

```
int n = 10000; // колчество записей
List<List<int>> a = new List<List<int>>(n);
foreach ( /* перебрать все записи */)
{
    // parent_id - id родителя
    // child_id - id ребёнка
    a[parent_id].Add(child_id);
    a[child_id].Add(parent_id);
}
```

Здесь a[i] - список тех вершин, которые смежны с вершиной i.
Но надо определиться, будет ли граф ориентированный, или нет.
Если граф ориентированный, то надо добавлять только рёбра из родителя в потомка, или только из потомка в родителя (зависит от того, что потом с этим графом делать). Если граф неориентированный, то надо оба ребра добавить

Матрица смежности не годится из-за того, что потребуется массив размера 10^8

Comment: мне кажется, это решение не подойдет. Построенное дерево я буду предавать web-клиенту в виде Json и по на основании этого Json будет строиться меню на клиенте.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно отсортируете данные в запросе, то можно не менять ничего и построить потом дерево за один проход.

```
PAR_ID  CHI_ID CHI_NOM
0            1  G1
1            2  G1-1
2            3  G1-1-1
2            4  G1-1-2
1            5  G1-2
0            6  G2
```

Вот хорошая статья про [Хранение иерархических структур в БД](https://habrahabr.ru/post/263629/)

Comment: дорогостоящая операция, время выполнения запроса значительно увеличилось.